# Some external files included in the package are not installed

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, filesystems, apk, adt

I've to use external files because I need to create a page as a web page with StageWebView, and I need these files : 1 HTML file, 2 PNG files, 1 Javascript file.
There is a problem when I want to use these files, I can't access them because I think they are omitted when APK package is installed. However, I can see them into the APK file after I have created it (I can open it as a traditionnal archive).

Unfortunely, after the installation, there is not my files at the expected place : I look at my OS file system, using the file explorer entry into the Android Device Monitor of Android SDK, the  tool located at folder `AndroidSDK_folder\tools\monitor.bat.`
I've writed this command line to package the APK, I don't think to do any errors here, it's very simple...

```
adt -package -target apk-emulator -storetype pkcs12 -keystore "my-Certificate.p12" -storepass password "my-APK.apk"  "src\my-Descriptor-app.xml" "my-SWF.swf" -C src\assets -e src\assets\1.html -e src\assets\image1.png image1.png -e src\assets\image2.png image2.png -e src\assets\my-JS.js my-JS.js
```

My files are not "embeded" in the code, it seems to be the reason of losing files at the installation step : Is it true ?

Comment: This post helps me, it could help someone else... http://forums.adobe.com/message/4238492#4238492 . I was astouning but it work for me : you must see specificaly the GOOD syntax of -C parameter !